# "In" o "a" per indicare edifici in città?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Sto scrivendo una relazione su un edificio storico, leggendo quelle dei miei colleghi trovo frasi del tipo "l'ospedale **in** Roma", o "la chiesa di San Martino **in** Bologna".

Io personalmente ho sempre utilizzato la preposizione "a" e sinceramente mi sembra che suoni meglio. C'è qualche motivo per cui dovrei preferire la preposizione "in"?

Comment: Secondo me, nei tuoi frammenti sono sottintese parole come 'sito' o 'ubicato', cioè 'la presente relazione riguarda la Chiesa di San Martino **sita** in Roma'. However, a me non piace usare *in* in that way, but I wouldn't use 'a', though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso che il primo esempio sia semplicemente sbagliato e servirebbe invece un complemento di specificazione: "l'ospedale *di* Roma". Se questa frase fa scattare un campanello d'allarme in testa ("*l'*ospedale di Roma? Roma ha solo un ospedale?"), siete in buona compagnia: entrambe le frasi sono ambigue, ma la seconda lo è IMVHO in modo più chiaro ed è quindi da preferirsi.

Per quanto riguarda il secondo, mentre si potrebbe fare la stessa obiezione, ho l'impressione che si tratti di una specie di vezzo stilistico: se si usasse il complemento di specificazione avremmo "la chiesa *di* San Martino *di* Bologna", che fa ripetizione; specificando invece la chiesa con un complemento di stato in luogo si aggira il problema. Perchè allora scegliere "in"?

Che io sappia nei complementi di stato in luogo in Italiano si può usare sia "in" che "a" in modo pressocchè equivalente; in Latino, però, questo complemento usa esclusivamente la preposizione "in" ("ad" è per il moto *a* luogo.) Se il contesto è sufficientemente aulico (e.g. storia dell'arte), è facile che il motivo della scelta sia quello di un più o meno consapevole latinismo.

Comment: Complimenti per il "campanello d'allarme", aggirabile volendo con frasi come "..., un ospedale di Roma, ...".

Answer (score 1):

La preposizione *in* per indicare gli edifici (o i borghi) è ora fuori moda e quindi non più molto usata. Si trova però in molti nomi noti, espressioni fisse e nel linguaggio ufficiale (o che vuole sembrare ufficiale).

Ci sono moltissimi casi in cui il nome ufficiale o comunemente usato, essendo stato stabilito tempo fa, usa la preposizione *in*.

Esempi:

- *l'opedale Fatebenefratelli **in** Roma*: http://www.fatebenefratelli-isolatiberina.it/Download/Fund%20rising%20-%20Raccolta%20Fondi_privacy.pdf
- *Basilica di San Giovanni **in** Laterano*: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_di_San_Giovanni_in_Laterano
- *San Giovanni **in** Persiceto*: perché nel ducato di Persiceto (i.e. *pescheto*) http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Giovanni_in_Persiceto

Answer (score 0):

Immagino che l'uso della preposizione "in" in questi casi sia dovuto all'importazione dall'inglese, visto che in quel caso si direbbe appunto "The hospital in Rome" e così via.

In italiano quando devi indicare la presenza in un edificio in città utilizza la preposizione "a", per le regioni e le nazioni (o anche per le tipologie di territorio) invece usi "in", ad esempio "L'ospedale in Lombardia", "L'ospedale in Francia", "L'ospedale in montagna".

Comment: Non credo che l'influsso dell'inglese sia rilevante.

Comment: @egreg Pensavo potesse esserlo per far capire agli utenti per quale motivo potrebbe nascere il dubbio in chi sta imparando la lingua venendo dall'inglese, che essendo parlato un po' ovunque può spingere ad adottare di default i suoi comportamenti nell'imparare un nuovo linguaggio... :)

Comment: anche io sono dello stesso parere di @egreg posso citarti almeno due libri ottocenteschi, a quel tempo di sicuro si era ben lontani dall'uso di anglicismi, per esempio "Il Fondaco dei Turchi **in** Venezia: Studi storici ed artistici" di Agostino Sagredo 1860 e "La chiesa e il seminario di Santa Maria della Salute **in** Venezia" di Giannantonio Moschini 1842. Temo che la tua risposta sia sbagliata...Grazie comunque.

Comment: Giusta osservazione... :)